# ERROR: Github token not set in environment, please set the GITHUB_TOKEN environment variable and retry

Tags: linux, testing, mersenne-twister, github-token

I am using git default test for zephyr's pr, when I running twister test, below issue occur:

```
Run python3 /home/runner/work/_actions/zephyrproject-rtos/action-manifest/f223dce[28](https://github.com/XXX/zephyr/actions/runs/6361203060/job/17275474588?pr=5#step:4:30)8b0d8f[30](https://github.com/XXX/zephyr/actions/runs/6361203060/job/17275474588?pr=5#step:4:32)bfd[57](https://github.com/XXX/zephyr/actions/runs/6361203060/job/17275474588?pr=5#step:4:59)eb2b14b18c230a7d8b/action.py -p "west.yml" \
Github token not set in environment, please set the GITHUB_TOKEN environment variable and retry.
['/home/runner/work/_actions/zephyrproject-rtos/action-manifest/f223dce288b0d8f30bfd57eb2b14b18c230a7d8b/action.py', '-p', 'west.yml', '--checkout-path', 'zephyrproject/zephyr', '-m', 'none', '-l', 'manifest', '--label-prefix', 'manifest-', '--dnm-labels', 'DNM', '--where', 'comment', '-v', '1', '--use-tree-checkout', 'true']
Running action __zephyrproject-rtos_action-manifest from workflow Manifest in XXX/zephyr
Event pull_request_target in /home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow/event.json and workspace /home/runner/work/zephyr/zephyr
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I added GITHUB_TOKEN to my computer environment variable and re executed below command:

```
git add 
git commit -s 
git push
```

However, these methods seem to have no effect. So I want to know how to pass this twister test? Is there any other thing i must to excute?